# I don't understand how Keras behaves when Dropout exists

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, dropout

I built a Neural Network with Dropout using Keras in Python. I want to find out how this network updates the weights. For simplicity, only one training data was prepared.

I trained the model under the following conditions:
(1): Model that doesn't include the Dropout layer
(2): Model that includes the Dropout layer and has the keyword training = False (Dropout is ignored during the prediction stage)
(3): Model that includes the Dropout layer and sets the keyword training = True (Dropout is also used in the prediction stage)

(I want to use (3) to evaluate the uncertainty of the predicted value.)

After the model completed the training phase, I looked at the amount of weight updates in the model.
Specifically, I show source code and execution results.

[Program]

```
drrate = 0.5

sample_x = np.array([[10]])
sample_y = np.array([1])

# Model
input_layer = Input(shape=(1,))
dence = input_layer
dence = Dropout(drrate)(dence, training=False)　# In Condition (1), this line doesn't use.
dence = Dense(2,
                kernel_initializer= wi.glorot_normal(seed=0),
                bias_initializer= wi.glorot_normal(seed=1)
                )(dence)
dence = Activation("sigmoid")(dence)
dence = Dense( 1 ,
                kernel_initializer= wi.glorot_normal(seed=2),
                bias_initializer= wi.glorot_normal(seed=3)
              )(dence)
dence = Activation("linear")(dence)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=dence)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit(sample_x, sample_y)
weights = model.get_weights()
print("-----------Training-----------")
print(weights)
print("w11 : ", (weights[0][0][0] - w_11) )
print("w12 : ", (weights[0][0][1] - w_12) )
print("w21 : ", (weights[2][0][0] - w_21) )
print("w22 : ", (weights[2][1][0] - w_22) )

print("b11 : ", (weights[1][0] - b_11) )
print("b12 : ", (weights[1][1] - b_12) )
print("b21 : ", (weights[3][0] - b_21) )
```

[Result]
We ran several simulations and summarized their results.
(The result shows the "update amount" of the weight.)

```
(Condition : 1)
・Pattern - 1
w11 :  0.00074356794
w12 :  0.00074353814
w21 :  -0.00073981285
w22 :  -0.0007440895
b11 :  0.00073862076
b12 :  0.00073826313
b21 :  -0.0007441044


(Condition : 2)
・Pattern - 1
w11 :  0.00074356794
w12 :  0.00074353814
w21 :  -0.00073981285
w22 :  -0.0007440895
b11 :  0.00073862076
b12 :  0.00073826313
b21 :  -0.0007441044

・Pattern - 2
w11 :  0.0009992719
w12 :  0.0009991974
w21 :  -0.0009942055
w22 :  -0.0009999275
b11 :  0.0009925961
b12 :  0.0009920597
b21 :  -0.0009999275

(Condition : 3)
・Pattern - 1
w11 :  0.0009864867
w12 :  0.0009983182
w21 :  -0.0008209944
w22 :  -0.0009999424
b11 :  0.0007850528
b12 :  0.0009675026
b21 :  -0.0009999275

・Pattern - 2
w11 :  0.0
w12 :  0.0
w21 :  0.0009999871
w22 :  0.0009999871
b11 :  -0.0009999275
b12 :  -0.0009996891
b21 :  0.0010000467

・Pattern - 3
w11 :  0.0007340908
w12 :  0.0007428825
w21 :  -0.0006109476
w22 :  -0.0007440895
b11 :  0.0005841851
b12 :  0.0007199049
b21 :  -0.0007441044
```

The results showed that:

・ Update amount is corrected when Dropout is enabled

・ The correction method differs depending on whether the training is True or False.

However, I have the following questions:

・ Why there is no "pattern whose update amount is 0" in condition 2?

・ Why do you get 3 patterns results instead of 2 patterns in condition 3?

・Why doesn't condition 3 produce the same result as condition 1 and 2?

I don't understand how Keras behaves when Dropout exists.
Help me.

Comment: I don't get why are  you looking at the weights and its relation to Dropout.

Comment: I want to understand how is NN with Dropout trained and does compute output, because I can trust the calculation result. If I cannot explain their behavior, I think I should not use them.

Comment: Sure, but what does Dropout have to do with weights? What do you understand about how dropout works?

Comment: From prior knowledge and experimental results, I believe that Dropout works as follows during the learning phase.
training = False: Change output value to 0 with probability drrate, output value does not change with probability (1-drrate).
training = True: Output value is changed to 0 with probability drrate, and output value is multiplied by 1 / (1-drrate) with probability (1-drrate).

Comment: On the other hand, I believe that Dropout works at the prediction stage as follows.
training = False: Dropout layer is completely ignored. (i.e. In most cases, the network at the prediction stage is larger than the network at the learning stage)
training = True: Output value is changed to 0 with probability drrate, and output value is multiplied by 1 / (1-drrate) with probability (1-drrate).

Comment: But there are problems that I don't understand.

1. Why there is no "pattern whose update amount is 0" in condition 2?
Condition-2 Pattern-1 is probably the result of not dropping, which is what I expected.
Therefore, Pattern-2 is considered to have been dropped.
In Pattern-2, the output value during forward propagation is 0 due to Dropout, so the output value during backward propagation should also be 0.
So, I think the weight update should be 0, but it's not.
(In Condition-3, there is a pattern whose weight update amount is 0.)
This is why I focused on weights.

Comment: 2.Why do you get 3 patterns results instead of 2 patterns in condition 3?
In this simulation, only one node of Dence1 can be dropped.
So you should get only two patterns of results.
However, in Condition-3, there are three patterns of results.

3.Why doesn't condition 3 produce the same result as condition 1 and 2?
If a drop occurs in Condition-3, the output value will be 0, so the correction 1 / (1-drrate) should have no effect.
So you should get the same result as Condition-1 and Condition-2.
However, no such results were obtained.

Comment: What you are asking is just interpreting your experiments, and I don't think we understand your experiments (not enough detail). And still you have not answered why are you looking at the model weights with Dropout, as Dropout does not directly affect the model weights. To me the whole question makes no sense due to that fact.

Comment: Some lectures would be a better place to clear concepts. I suggest you refer andrew ng's lecture on dropout. That will clear  your concept and will tell you what and what not to look for

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for answering.
I did not fully understand Dropout. I will study again.
This problem has been resolved. Thank you very much.